# How do I conditionally update a document using a POCO with the Firebase .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-firestore

It seems like to update a document when you have deserialized it into a POCO can only be done via the `SetAsync(...)` method. No `UpdateAsync(...)` overloads take a POCO.

The problem is that only `UpdateAsync(...)` takes the crucial `Precondition` parameter, so that's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore SDKs will always overwrite the full object when you pass a POCO.

If you want to perform a partial update, you'll need to put the fields you want to update in a map/dictionary and call `Update..` or `Set(..., { merge: true })` with that.

Comment: Thanks, it's not a partial update I need, but the normal save-whole-document-if-not-modified semantics. I've actually since opened a GitHub issue with the SDK team because I don't think I'm confused, it's actually a missing feature/oversight.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/7677

Comment: "if-not-modified" is not something that I'm aware of in Firestore. Note that Jon gave the same answer as I did here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/7677#issuecomment-1010266174, and Sebastian confirmed here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/7677#issuecomment-1010417581

Comment: There is a `Precondition.LastUpdate(Timestamp)` that appears to be the mechanism for the "lost update" problem. There's no ETag, which is fine if modified times are reliable.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I never heard of that, and it's actually a good usage of the (otherwise hardly visible) timestamp that Firestore keeps. 